# urllib.request: any way to read from it without modifying the request object?

Tags: python, urllib

Given a standard `urllib.request` object, retrieved so:

```
req = urllib.urlopen('http://example.com')
```

If I read its contents via `req.read()`, afterwards the request object will be empty.

Unlike normal file-like objects, however, the request object does not have a `seek` method, for I am sure are excellent reasons.

However, in my case I have a function, and I want it to make certain determinations about a request and then return that request "unharmed" so that it can be read again.

I understand that one option is to re-request it. But I'd like to be able to avoid making multiple HTTP requests for the same url & content.

The only other alternative I can think of is to have the function return a tuple of the extracted content and the request object, with the understanding that anything that calls this function will have to get the content in this way.

Is that my only option?

Comment: Don't use `urllib.urlopen` - [*Also note that the urllib.urlopen() function has been removed in Python 3 in favor of urllib2.urlopen()*](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html)

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, although in this case the behavior from `urllib2.urlopen` is the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delegate the caching to a `StringIO` object(code not tested, just to give the idea):

```
import urllib
from io import StringIO


class CachedRequest(object):
    def __init__(self, url):
        self._request = urllib.urlopen(url)
        self._content = None

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        # if attr is not defined in CachedRequest, then get it from
        # the request object.
        return getattr(self._request, attr)

    def read(self):
        if self._content is None:
            content = self._request.read()
            self._content = StringIO()
            self._content.write(content)
            self._content.seek(0)
            return content
        else:
            return self._content.read()

    def seek(self, i):
        self._content.seek(i)
```

If the code actually expects a real `Request` object(i.e. calls `isinstance` to check the type) then subclass `Request` and you don't even have to implement `__getattr__`.

Note that it is possible that a function checks for the exact class(and in this case you can't do nothing) or, if it's written in C, calls the method using C/API calls(in which case the overridden method wont be called).

Comment: Wouldn't you need to set up `self._content` to be something like `StringIO` instead of `None`? Pretty sure you'd run in to an `AttributeError` when calling `write`.

Comment: @JordanReiter Sorry. At the beginning I wrote `self._content = StringIO()` then I changed my mind and forgot to fix that bit of code that assumed `self._content` was already initialized.

Answer (score 2):

Make a subclass of `urllib2.Request` that uses a `cStringIO.StringIO` to hold whatever gets read. Then you can implement `seek` and so forth. Actually you could just use a string, but that'd be more work.